# render button based on checkbox count

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I'm trying to disable or enable a button based on checkboxes. if two more are checked the button is no longer disabled. This part works but I'm not sure how to disable the buttons again if I uncheck items.

i'm new to vue but I'm wondering how to find out if each checkbox has been either checked OR unchecked so I can correctly move my counter up or down.

```
 <li class="listItemsModal" v-for="(student, index) in students">
                                <input v-model="student.exclude" @change="toggleAddButton" id="student.index" type="checkbox" > 
                                {{student.first_name}}

                            </li>
```

if the button is clicked we add and check to see if the value is bigger than 2
I need some way to access the checked value to see if checked or not, then go up or down accordingly

```
 toggleAddButton: function(){
                   console.log(this.studentsAdded)
                   this.studentsAdded ++
                   if(this.studentsAdded >= 2){
                    this.disableAdd = false
                   }else{
                    this.disableAdd = true 
                   }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, some are easier or harder depending on your data structures.

If your `students` [array is fully reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) you could have a computed property that updates any time that object changes. Something like:

```js
// ... vue stuff...
computed:{
  // ... your other computed properties
  enoughBoxesChecked(){
    // you could also use an accumulator, but this is very easy to read.
    return this.students.filter(student=>student.exclude).length > 2;
  }
}
// ... other vue stuff
```

Then you could use that `enoughBoxesChecked` computed property on the button you want to disable. Something like `<button :disabled="enoughBoxesChecked">...`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I do have an exclude prop For each students so I definitely think that'll be the easiest way. I’ll update you with the results :)

Comment: Yes this worked for me! luckily I already had that v-model students.exclude setup in my render :) thank you